# How to auto-select the value of a dropdown using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert this JavaScript into jQuery?

The purpose of this is to auto-select the value of a dropdown that matches.

**JS code :**

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByName("title")[0].value="the_title_value";
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you not know how to select the element? To set its value? Something else?

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript. Why bother converting and what's the actual issue?

Comment: All of the answers are doing what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the elements by their `name` attribute, then get the `:first` of them before setting the current `val()`, like this:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {   
    $('select[name="title"]:first').val('the_title_value') 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // document.getElementsByName("title")[0].value="the_title_value";
  // get all items with name "title" and then reduce the result set to the first element and then set the value
  $('[name="title"]').first().val("the_title_value");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="title">
  <option value='the_title_value_1'>the_title_value_1</option>
  <option value='the_title_value'>the_title_value</option>
  <option value='the_title_value_3'>the_title_value_3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, and if the `select` has the desired `name` this will work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select[name="title"]').first().val("the_title_value");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="title">
<option value='the_title_value1'>1</option>
<option value='the_title_value'>2</option>
<option value='the_title_valu3'>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:eq` and `name` selector inside `ready` function to achieve that , check the example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(function(){
  $("select[name='title']:eq(0)").val('second');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="title">
  <option value='first'>First 1</option>
  <option value='second'>Second 2</option>
  <option value='third'>Third 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm not changing any value !!? where you see that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[name="title"]').val("the_title_value");
    })
```

you only need first() if you have many elements with name="title" on the page. The reason why you have to put [0] in vanila javascript is because

```
    document.getElementsByName("title")
```

returns an array of elements, even if there is only one with this name.

Answer (score 0):

For ***programmatically*** selecting a ***select element*** (drop-down list), if you have an ***Id*** on your select element, then jQuery makes it as simple as assigning a value to the element.

```
let dynamicValue = 'xyz';  //just ensure this value is on the target list
$("#idOfSelect").val(dynamicValue);
```

Please note that the *onChange event will **not** be triggered* by this. Also, the DOM state should be Ready as already pointed out by others.